# What process do you use to start a BMX program in an area without one?

Tags: bmx, learning, reference

i would like to start a BMX program for our local youth. How do you go about setting one up?

Comment: Hi Bret. Welcome to bikes stackexchange. I unfortunately had to flag this as too broad as there won’t be a single answer to your question and any answer is likely going to be too specific for the circumstances. This would be a better question for a chat forum such as reddit or our own chat room.

Comment: @Robo Hi Karen. I'm hoping to get a few answers before there's a quorum on the flag. I've talked with my librarian and I think maybe this is a book I'll have to write, based on what it appears I'll have to learn by going bald. :)

Comment: You may just want to talk to local youth groups. There’s nothing special about a youth bmx group that differentiates it from day a youth little league. You need land, liability insurance, money, and volunteer leaders. But how you get all three will vary tremendously by locale.

Comment: True. I may be overthinking it. The challenge I'm addressing is that I see a need, but the culture in this region doesn't recognize it. There are some other things I'm doing to change the culture (trying to open rail trails, etc) but I don't know how to develop a culture around a sport in a vacuum. I'm hoping someone says, "Yeah, it was like that here, and ..."

Comment: So should I delete "closed" questions?